# When I setObject to NSMutableDictionary previous objects added are deleted

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsmutabledictionary

This is the code to add objects to a NSMutableDictionary:

```
-(void)mapUserFields: (UIControl *) sender  {

nsd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

int tagValue = sender.tag;
UITextField *field  = [sender viewWithTag: tagValue];

[nsd setObject:field.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tagValue]];

NSLog(@"\nfield.text: %@  tagValue: %d  nsd.count: %d\n",field.text, tagValue, nsd.count);
}
```

This is the output from the debugger console:

```
2014-09-17 15:18:10.022 Books[20738:60b] 
field.text: 2  tagValue: 0  nsd.count: 1
2014-09-17 15:18:11.394 Books[20738:60b] 
field.text: 4  tagValue: 1  nsd.count: 1
2014-09-17 15:18:16.918 Books[20738:60b] 
field.text: 6  tagValue: 2  nsd.count: 1
2014-09-17 15:18:18.863 Books[20738:60b] dictionary.count: 1
```

As you can see, the count remains at 1, but the data is valid.  What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by Josh above, this line is your problem:

```
nsd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

because it replaces the entire dictionary with a new one. So it isn't that adding one key is removing another, it's that you're explicitly throwing the earlier data away.

Perhaps try:

```
if (nds == nil) {
    nsd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared NSMutableDictionary 'nsd' Globally and you are allocating  memory and initializing the dictionary whenever some control event has fired.Instead of initialising it every time, you can initialise it in viewDidLoad method of your view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   nsd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 
}
```

And then in your method add objects to dictionary

```
- (void)mapUserFields:(UIControl *) sender
{
    int tagValue = sender.tag;
    UITextField *field  = [sender viewWithTag: tagValue];

   [nsd setObject:field.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tagValue]];

   NSLog(@"\nfield.text: %@  tagValue: %d  nsd.count: %d\n",field.text, tagValue,                        nsd.count);
}
```